# Regex negative lookahead trouble

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I'm having trouble getting negative lookahead to work.

I would like to catch all lines mentioning  "warning" or "error" in a file, but not if that line alsow mentions "clearmake".

So it should catch this:

```
This is a warning : bla bla
```

but not this:

```
clearmake.exe: This is a warning : bla bla
```

I've played around with negative lookahead, but I can't get it to work

```
(?!clearmake).*$
```

Any idees? Thanks!

Comment: How do you suppose to match "warning" or "error" without mentioning them in your expression?

Comment: Definitely a strings manipulation work :)

Comment: And why using regex for that?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I couldn't even get the lookahead part to work properly, so I didn't include my attempt at matching warning and error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in regex, but you need advanced regex understanding for that. Probably it would be easier to read/understand if you use 2 `if()` or logical operators and normal string search for this task.

You should always give the **language tag** for such questions, that gives the chance for alternative answers.

I explain a regex solution, I assume you are reading that file row by row.

1. You want to match `warning` **OR** `error` ==> use an alternation `\b(?:error|warning)\b`.
2. But not in a row that includes `clearmake` ==> `^(?!.*\bclearmake\b)`

So your regex looks like this:

```
^(?!.*\bclearmake\b).*\b(?:error|warning)\b
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?33rn8)

- `\b` is a [wordboundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to avoid partial matches
- `^` is an [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) for the start of the string
- `(?!.*\bclearmake\b)` [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
^(?!.*\bclearmake\b).*(warning|error).*$
    ---------------
        |
        |->match further only if the string doesn't have clearmake
```